# How to slide a bootstrap glyphicon in list items using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to slide down bootstrap glyph icon **plus** symbol to the bottom of the last child of each parent. How can I do this. [Click here JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ann7tctp/92/)

***eg:***

Parent has Item 1 and child has item 1.1, item 1.2, item 1.3. When we click on the parent. I need to show glyph icon on the bottom of each child.

**HTML**

```
<span id="slidedown">Slide down</span>
<table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Continente</th>
                <th>Capital</th>
                <th>Lengua</th>
                <th>Habitantes</th>
                <th>Moneda</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                            <tr><td colspan="0">
    <div style="" class="row">
        <div style="" class="form-group col-md-12">
            <div style="" class="col-md-2">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Nombre</label>
            </div>
            <div style="" class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Nombre del país" id="update-name" name="name" value="France" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="" class="form-group col-md-12">
            <div style="" class="col-md-2">
                <label for="continent" class="control-label">Continente</label>
            </div>
            <div style="" class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Continente donde se encuentra" id="update-continent" name="continent" value="" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="" class="form-group col-md-12">
            <div style="" class="col-md-2">
                <label for="capital" class="control-label">Capital</label>
            </div>
            <div style="" class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Ciudad capital" id="update-capital" name="capital" value="" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="" class="form-group col-md-12">
            <div style="" class="col-md-2">
                <label for="language" class="control-label">Lengua</label>
            </div>
            <div style="" class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Lengua oficial" id="update-language" name="language" value="" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="" class="form-group col-md-12">
            <div style="" class="col-md-2">
                <label for="population" class="control-label">Habitantes</label>
            </div>
            <div style="" class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Número total de habitantes" id="update-population" name="population" value="0" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="" class="form-group col-md-12">
            <div style="" class="col-md-2">
                <label for="currency" class="control-label">Moneda</label>
            </div>
            <div style="" class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Moneda que se usa" id="update-currency" name="currency" value="" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="" class="form-group col-md-12">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk btn btn-success"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle btn btn-primary"></span>
            <input name="update-id" value="1" type="hidden">
        </div>
    </div>
</td></tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '#slidedown', function(event) {
        var row = $('.table > tbody').find('tr');
        row.find('div.row').hide().slideDown('400');
    });
```

**CSS**

```
.just-padding {
    padding: 15px;
}

.list-group.list-group-root {
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.list-group.list-group-root .list-group {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root .list-group-item {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group-item:first-child {
    border-top-width: 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group > .list-group-item {
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group > .list-group > .list-group-item {
    padding-left: 45px;
}

.list-group-item .glyphicon {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: at the bottom of which child? all of them? and what do you mean by 'bottom'? can you describe it better or maybe set picture of end result?

Comment: @jakob, Bottom means item 1.3,  item 2.3, item 3.3. I need plus glyph icon on the last child of each parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by adding specific class to your first submenu links, loop through all main menus/links and then add icon to last link in submenu that contains specific class.

Something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('div[id^="item-"]').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.submenu2').last().append('<span id="slidedown" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span>');
  });
  $('.list-group-item').on('click', function() {
    $('.glyphicon-chevron-right', this).toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
  });
});
```

Full code here https://jsfiddle.net/ann7tctp/95/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. I have changed css for fun..

```
        $(function() {

      $('.list-group-item').on('click', function() {
        $('.glyphiconRight', this)
          .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right')
          .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
      });

      $( ".list-group-item:last-child" )
      .css({ color:"red", fontSize:"80%" })
      .append('<span id="slidedown" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span>');

    });
```